# Grab the element with d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick

I'm trying to learn d3js library. Faced with the problem of the capture table's TD element by clicking. I usually use this way

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.getElementById("table_id").addEventListener("click",function(e){
            var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;

            if(elem.nodeName != "TD") return;

...
    }
...
```

So i need to do something like that in d3js. But I don't know how to substitute .target and .srcElement methods. 
What I do have

```
d3.select(#table_id).on('click',function(){
    var elem = ???
```

In `this` i have my table. In `d3.event` such information `click clientX=327, clientY=129`. The `d` is undefined

Please, help me to grab TD element in var.

Comment: Problem solved by `d3.event.target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3js is very flexible and you don't need to use `d3.event.target` every time.

As you asked, some details missed in your code:

**1.** **Selection**

There are two selection functions in `d3` :

`d3.select()` it gets or finds specific `tag` or `element` or `class` or `tag id`, for example:

`d3.select('div')` returns first div or `d3.select('.active')` find tag  have class named active. In your case you should use`d3.select('#table_id')` you missed single quotation in select function.

The next d3 selection function is `d3.selectAll()` that act like `d3.select()` but the difference is this function select all the parameters, for example :

`d3.selectAll('p')` return all the `p` tags or all Id or classes get as parameter.

**2.** **different between this and d**

`this` is an argument that use to select specific tag you try to select or do some stuff on it and is more usable in `selectAll` function because you don't know which tag selected.

`d` is an object or `DOM` that contain all the properties and events.

So I changed your code and hope it's help you to learn `d3` better.

```
d3.select("#table_id").on("click",function(){

            var elem=d3.select(this);
            if(elem.attr("name")!=="TD")
                  return;

});
```

more information [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections).